# How to remove xib file for UIViewController class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I want to remove xib file for UIViewController classes. Please let me know, If any one know how to remove or delete xib file.

Comment: You wanna delete in your xcode ?

Comment: `right click -> delete` not working?

Comment: Hardest question seen on Stackoverflow :) who knows how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can just delete the .xib file,**

[image]

### ***If you want a new .xib for your view controller, create new xib***

[image]

Then give **ViewController** as File's Owner's **Custom Class**,

[image]

Finally, link the ViewCrontroller's view and .xib

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that the labels and everything I had placed in the file still showed up in the Simulator after I had deleted my .xib

It seems, Simulator caches the contents and I had to delete the app from inside the Simulator to force it to totally rebuild. Worked after that.

Comment: Yup. It's super annoying. Always delete and reinstall the app after deleting a xib. I keep meaning to file a radar on that.